# Loop device with 4K sectors

Tags: loop-device

Using the `losetup` command, you can turn a regular file into a pretend block device. You can then partition and format it like any other device.

Is there some way to make Linux pretend that this "device" has a 4K logical sector size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible: If you run

```shell
losetup --help
```

you will notice the option

```
-b, --sector-size
```

I suggest also testing to use the `direct-IO` option too on the loop block device

Here is how I create my loop devices :

```shell
losetup --sector-size 4096 --direct-io=on $loop_device $diskfile
```

But maybe in your case, only `--sector-size 4096` is sufficient.

You can then display the loop devices with the `losetup -l` command:

```
NAME          SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                            DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop4000         0      0         0  0 /mnt/fbx/FBX-24T/testspeed2            1    4096
/dev/loop3000         0      0         0  0 /mnt/fbx/FBX-24T/testspeed             1    4096
```

Please note the 4K block sectors

Please also note that for the moment, you can specify the sector size from 512 to 4096 but for example it's not possible to use 8K sectors (8192), the `losetup` command will fail if you try to use sectors size bigger than 4096.

Here is why I suggest using `direct-IO` option:  `--direct-io=on`

When you have a 4K sectors formated filesystem on the underlying file used to create the loop device (see `losetup -P` or `losetup --partscan` option), using the `direct-IO` option will bypass the kernel storage stack working queue by sending the IO directly to the block device.

It helps keeping coherent (aligned) the block device and the filesystem you're writing on.

In some case, it also provide 8 to 10 times better performance, for example when creating a loop device from a LUKS file hosted on a CIFS share
(LUKS = Linux Unified Key Setup aka `Cryptsetup` which add a crypted layer between the block device and its hosted filesystems)

Comment: Why would you recommend `--direct-io=on`? (Please update your question to clarify, as otherwise it's essentially the same as [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100907/100397))

Comment: Be carefull, the answer you specify is talking about the 'fdisk' command and not the 'losetup' command.
I suggest using '--direct-io=on' if you have a 4K sectors formated filesystem on the underlying file used to create the loop device (see losetup '--partscan' option), it will bypass the kernel storage stack working queue by sending the IO directly to the block device. It helps keeping coherent (aligned) the block device and the filesystem you're writing on. In some case, it also provide 8 times better performance, ex: when creating a loop device from a LUKS file hosted on a CIFS share

Answer (score 5):

`fdisk` has a number of switches:

> **-b sectorsize**
>
> Specify the sector size of the disk.  Valid values  are  512,  1024,
>       2048  or 4096.  (Recent kernels know the sector size.  Use this only
>             on old kernels or to override  the  kernel's  ideas.)   Since  util-
>             linux-2.17, fdisk differentiates between logical and physical sector
>             size.  This option changes both sector sizes to sectorsize.
>
> **-C cyls**
>
> Specify the number of cylinders of the disk.  I  have  no  idea  why
>                 anybody would want to do so.
>
> **-H heads**
>
> Specify  the number of heads of the disk.  (Not the physical number,
>                 of course, but the number used for  partition  tables.)   Reasonable
>                 values are 255 and 16.

That's not me editorializing *("I  have  no  idea  why anybody would want to do so.")*.  Kind of nice someone included functionality they didn't see a use for at the time.

Comment: I notice based on your other question you were more interested in the GPT format.  I'd guess you can use `fdisk` to partition the device, then apply `gdisk` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not at a low level. It is certainly possible to tell some mkfs dispatch utilities that they should use a certain block size when formatting though. See the man page of the specific `mkfs.*` tool for further information.

Comment: I'm more interested in partitioning tools such as `gdisk`, but thanks.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: Those are easy though. Most of them can have a specific drive geometry forced upon them via the command line.

Comment: I can't find a switch to `gdisk` to do this...

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate in your question what exact problem you are facing with `gdisk`. The solution may be something else entirely.

Comment: That only changes the partition alignment, not what `gdisk` thinks the sector size is. The GPT header is still 512 bytes from the start of the disk.

Comment: See the `-b` switch in `man fdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

Latest losetup should have this feature: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/a1a41597bfd55e709024bd91aaf024159362679c